# If $abc=1$ where $a,b,c>0$, then show that $(a-1+b^{-1})(b-1+c^{-1})(c-1+a^{-1}) \leq 1$.

Tags: inequality, contest-math, symmetric-polynomials

I tried writing everything in terms of $a$ and $c$, but got stuck at $(a-1+ac)(a+1-ac)(1-a+ac) \leq a^2c$ where I thought of trying to show for all $x,y,z>0$ that $(x-y+z)(x+y-z)(-x+y+z) \leq xyz $  and substitute $x=1, y=a$ and $z=ac$. However, I'm not sure if that inequality is even correct and I doubt that this approach will work, so I would like some hints or a piece of advice. I would be grateful for that.

Comment: Maybe try expanding it out?  I realize it will get pretty large, but there is a lot of symmetry, and the $abc$ will cancel out with the $1$ for example.  And, $b^{-1}c^{-1} = a$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a=\frac{x}{y}$ and $b=\frac{y}{z},$ where $x$, $y$ and $z$ are positives.

Thus, $c=\frac{z}{x}$ and we need to prove that:
$$\prod_{cyc}\left(\frac{x}{y}-1+\frac{z}{y}\right)\leq1$$
$$\prod_{cyc}(x+z-y)\leq xyz$$ or $$\sum_{cyc}(x^3-x^2y-x^2z+xyz)\geq0.$$
Now, let $x\geq y\geq z$.

Thus, $$\sum_{cyc}(x^3-x^2y-x^2z+xyz)=\sum_{cyc}x(x-y)(x-z)\geq$$
$$\geq x(x-y)(x-z)+y(y-x)(y-z)=(x-y)^2(x+y-z)\geq0$$ and we are done!

Comment: What does cyc in the index stand for?

Comment: @C Squared It's a cyclic sum. For example, for three variables $x$, $y$ and $z$ we have $\sum\limits_{cyc}x=x+y+z,$ $\sum\limits_{cyc}x^2y=x^2y+y^2z+z^2x$... Also, I used a cyclic product. For example, $\prod\limits_{cyc}x=xyz,$ $\prod\limits_{cyc}xy=xy\cdot yz\cdot zx=x^2y^2z^2.$

Answer (score 1):

This is a well-known inequality from some years of IMO I think. After your substitution, use the following:

$$(x-y+z)(x+y-z)\leq\dfrac{(x-y+z+x+y-z)^2}{4}=x^2.$$

Comment: Isn't that just $(x-y+z)(x+y-z)=x^2-(y-z)^2\le x^2$?

Comment: I intended this as a hint, not a complete solution. Either exactly one or three of $x-y+z, y+z-x, z+x-y$ can be negative and in each cases LHS is non-positive, so the inequality is trivial.